# Auto increase size of input with text entered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a HTML code in which the users enter the comment for a particular question if the size of comments are big i want my text box to auto increase in height with the comments 
Below is my HTML code:

```
<label class="label-reports">Comments</label>
 <input  @((ViewBag.UserId != null && ViewBag.UserId == question.AnsweredBy) || (question.AnsweredBy == null) ? "" : "disabled")  type="text" class="form-control" style="align-content:stretch; min-width:1200Px; width: auto !important" for="comments" value="@question.Comments" />
```

I tried to implement this

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>*
```

but did not succeed can someone suggest to increase the size of text box with increase in text

Comment: can you show your issue in a fiddler? and, are you targeting any specific browser?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/s8k2ygtL/

Comment: as you can see in the fiddler if i enter more than certain character count we can see the comments but not the text box increase in size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For `<textarea>` Elements...**

If you aren't opposed to using a plug-in, you could use something like  [autosize](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/), which will allow your `<textarea>` element to grow as expected :

```
<!-- Example autosize.js CDN Reference -->
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autosize.js/3.0.15/autosize.min.js'></script>
<script>
    // Automatically size all of your <textarea> elements as you type
    autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
</script>
```

[image]

**Interactive Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Autosize Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <pre>Start typing (and press Enter a few times)</pre>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autosize.js/3.0.15/autosize.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**For `<input>` elements...**

`<input>` elements don't have to be left out. There is an aptly-named [autosize-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autosize-input) plug-in that essentially accomplishes the same basic thing :

```
<!-- Example autosize.js CDN Reference -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/yuanqing/autosize-input/master/autosize-input.min.js"></script>
<script>
    // Automatically size all of your <textarea> elements as you type
    autosizeInput(document.querySelector('#YourInputID'));
</script>
```

Comment: I want to include my auto sizing inside the <input/> i cant use this script so can you suggest me any thing that i can include in <input/>

Comment: I added an additional reference to a similar library that handles the same basic functionality with `<input>` elements.